# How to set up a button layout in xml which looks good in all screen sizes?

Tags: xml, android, android-xml

I have 4 buttons in a page, like the image following my question.
I don't want to change the positions of the buttons in screens with different sizes.
I don't know how could I do it.

What I want is like this image :

[image]

What I have is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,ContentDescription,UselessLeaf,UselessParent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/helpi"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/iconhelp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/categoryi"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/iconcategory" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/searchi"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/iconsearch" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/infoi"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/iconinfo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried anything??

Comment: first thing try something, and post your code here.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried. There are more than one ways to achieve this.

Comment: Place a blank textview  `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` and  `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`, align these buttons across the textview?

Comment: I mean to say please try to show us what have you coded. Your layout file and activity file..

Comment: Post your xml file for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

[image]

This is how it's rendered on a **240*320 ldpi** screen

[image]

This is how it's rendered on a **320*480 mdpi** screen

I got it by using this (the buttons images came out of a search on google):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTopLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ball"
            android:text="Btn 1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTopRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnTopLeft"
            android:background="@drawable/ball"
            android:text="Btn 2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBottomLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnTopLeft"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ball"
            android:text="Btn 3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBottomRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnTopRight"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnBottomLeft"
            android:background="@drawable/ball"
            android:text="Btn 4"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I used a small screen on emulator, to load faster